# Web scraping script works only after failed first attempt

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell, comobject

I have a script for automating a task in Internet Explorer. But the script works only after having failed the first time.

If I open `powershell.exe` and run the script, it gives me the error

> Cannot call method on null-valued expression.

but if I hit <kbd>F5</kbd> and run it again, it works perfect from then on. If I close PowerShell and reopen, the error is back again on first attempt.

The logic for the script is basicly this

```psh
$doc = $ie.Document;
$frames = @($doc.getElementsByTagName("FRAME"));

foreach ($frame in $frames) {
    try {
        $inputs = @($frame.ContentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT"));

        foreach ($button in $inputs |
                 where {$_.type -eq "button" -and $_.value -eq "Ny sag"}) {
            $button.click(); $x = 11;
        }
    } catch {
        Exception -errtxt $error[0] -custom_txt ("attempt # " + [string]$x);
    }
}
```

The code fails on the line

```psh
$inputs = @($frame.ContentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT"));
```

I tried to add default webclient but nothing changed.

```psh
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient;
$wc.Proxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

Comment: I wonder if the object `$ie` was not ready why you first call its properties. Perhaps put a sleep before this line `$doc = $ie.Document`

Comment: You show how you try to access the content of the web page, but how are you loading it? As @Matt said, loading/rendering of the page might not be finished on your first attempt.

Comment: Yes, thats it. Thank you both very much. After i add `while ($ie.readystate -ne 4)` before every call to the $ie object it works!